# Adding new students into a dictionary?

Tags: python

This is from the programming exercise at programming 21 fi Im trying to make this where it adds the students into the database as an dictionary and the print_student function shows the information about the student. Im having trouble with adding the students in the database correctly

```
def add_student(students, name):
    if name not in students:
        students[name] = set()
    students[name].add(name)
    
def print_student(students, name):
    amount_of_completed_courses = 0
    if students[name] == 0:
        return "No Completed courses"
    
    
    
        
        
students = {}
add_student(students,"Peter")
add_student(students, "Eliza")
print_student(students, "Peter")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to add `name` to `students[name]` -- that just gives you a dictionary of `name: {name}`, which might as well just be a single set of `name`s.

Based on your other code, what I'm guessing you want `students[name]` to be is a set of courses; when you add a student, that set should be empty, and you probably want a separate function to add a course for a given student.  `print_student` could then print that list of courses.  Something like:

```
def add_student(students, name):
    students[name] = set()

def print_student(students, name):
    print(students[name] or "No completed courses")

def add_course(students, name, course):
    students[name].add(course)
    
students = {}
add_student(students,"Peter")
add_course(students, "Peter", "Programming 21")
add_student(students, "Eliza")
print_student(students, "Peter")  # {'Programming 21'}
print_student(students, "Eliza")  # No completed courses
```

If you only intend to ever have one `students` dictionary, you can declare it before you define the functions, and then have the functions bind that value so it doesn't need to be passed in as an argument each time:

```
students = {}

def add_student(name):
    students[name] = set()

def print_student(name):
    print(students[name] or "No completed courses")
    
def add_course(name, course):
    students[name].add(course)
    
add_student("Peter")
add_course("Peter", "Programming 21")
add_student("Eliza")
print_student("Peter")  # {'Programming 21'}
print_student("Eliza")  # No completed courses
```

The advantage of this approach obviously is that it removes the repetition of always passing in `students` explicitly; the downside is that it makes it less flexible in that you can't swap in a fresh "database" (e.g. for testing purposes).